# How To Rotate Image In Place With jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, rotation

I am trying to make an image rotate in place with each click (the image is an old-fashioned TV knob). I cannot get it to work despite my best efforts.

The code is below:

```
    var value = 0
$("#img").rotate({ 
bind: 
{ 
    click: function(){
        value +=90;
        $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
    }
 }
```

});

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm new to here so it took a second. Thanks again for everything =)

Comment: Thanks. Also, once you get to 15 rep (I believe that's the level) that's when you can upvote which means "This answer is useful". Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm providing a jsFiddle that causes the div to rotate ***after every mouse click.***

Essentially, this is from **Example 5** of the [**jqueryrotate.js**](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples#Example_5) plugin.

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uCy76/)

Comment: To be honest, it still doesn't work (but I still appreciate the help). I don't know what I'm doing wrong or leaving out? I even have the "Current Stable Version of jQueryRotate(jsRotate)v.2.2"  @arttronics, you are correct. It is that example [http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples#Example_5]. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: @arttronics- it works! but- instead of the image rotating in place (like the example in jsFiddle) it follows a larger circular path, like the radius around a clock. Don't know why. I used the exact code that was given. Any ideas?

Comment: your code works in jsFiddle but when I do it on a test page in Chrome is operates like I mentioned above. Here is the jsFiddle link: (http://jsfiddle.net/UTvj6/) I added a different image than what I'm using, but other than that, it's all the same code.

Comment: HOOORAYYYYY! Got it. Thank you so much for taking the time to help. You are very kind.

Answer (score 3):

There is a jQuery patch, which enables you to do something like this:
http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html

```
$('#img').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({rotate: '+=10deg'}, 0);
});
```

Or this plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ which allow stuff like:

```
$("#img").rotate({
    bind: {
        click: function() {
            $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: (parseInt($(this).getRotateAngle()) + 10),
                easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo
            })
        }
    }
});​
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/mFY22/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example using a jquery plugin called [jqueryrotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

[See the jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mFY22/5/)

Comment: @arttronics I posted an update and now it rotates with each click, hope you reconsider ;) I didn't have much time when I posted, it was just a quick mock-up...

Comment: @arttronics now we're talkin' haha thanks, I must admit I was kind of lazy on that one!