# Image Rotate Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to rotate and image when i click on it but the code does not seem to work for me. Any help would be appreciated.
Martin.

```
<script src="jQueryRotate.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".gun4").click(function()
      {
          $(".gun4").rotate(90);
      });
});

<div id="pic">
<img src="Images/gun4.jpg" height="100" width="120" id="gun" class="gun4"/>
```

Comment: Are you loading jQuery? What errors do you get?

Comment: "...code does not seem to work for me." Please define "doesn't work."

Comment: Also, your code will cause all images with the gun4 class to rotate so if you have more than one with that class you'll want to rotate just the selected target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Rotate Image In Place With jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216769/how-to-rotate-image-in-place-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, i made some changes to it for testing purposes that you can check here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ef6mX/2/

```
var I = 0;
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".gun4").click(function()
      {
          $(".gun4").rotate(90*(I%4));
          I++;
      });
});
```

So check if your are loading Jquery correctly or if you are having errors.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/Ef6mX/6/ Update for independent clicks

Comment: thank you my jquery was not loaded correctly